# Ruby/Rails Percentage to decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixnum

Bit of a beginner question here...in my rails app I have a model for parts and I want admin to be able to apply a discount to the price of the part if they want to. The value of the discount in my parts model is an integer. I have a method inside my part model called apply_discount

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items
  belongs_to :category
  default_scope { where(active: true)}

  def apply_discount
    new_price = self.discount.to_decimal * self.price
    self.price - new_price
  end
```

The error I am getting is "undefined method `to_decimal' for 10:Fixnum"
whenever you put in a percentage of the discount. Any ideas how I can get the discount proper to convert into a float or to a decimal? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no `to_decimal` method for integers, but there's a `to_f` (to float).  You'll need to divide by 100 to get the discount percentage to work.

Also, you don't need to use `self.` unless you're assigning.

```
def apply_discount
  price - ( discount.to_f / 100 * price )
end
```